# How to take replace $ in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i have the string 'data' and it will output the following code

```
{
"success": true,
"lowest_price": "$0.06",
"volume": "237",
"median_price": "$0.04",
"market_hash_name": "MP9 | Storm (Minimal Wear)"
}
```

How can i call median_price with out the $ in it so it can be a number?

Answer (score 0):

```
parseFloat(data.median_price.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods available that we can use to remove `$` from your object.

1. You can use a `.slice` method as @Simon suggests. With `parseFloat` if you want to parse your `string` to `Float` or without parseFloat if want to keep it as string.
2. You can also use `.replace` method like

   ```
   data.median_price.replace('$', '');
   ```

   and to get the result as Float number we can do same thing as @Simon told in `.slice` method like,

   ```
   parseFloat(data.median_price.replace('$', ''));
   ```